# Add a class to a table with ckeditor dialog button

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm using ckeditor with the table plugin, which I think comes standard with the ckeditor module. What I want to do is to add a button in the table dialog modal that will then add a class to the table inserted.

I've been playing with this https://www.drupal.org/node/1793710, but I'm not sure how to hook into the dialog box.

Comment: In D7, you need to use the CKEditor API to do this see [Simple Plugin (part 1)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1)

Comment: i understand adding a plugin, but what i'm trying to do is to add a field to an already existing dialog.

Comment: hmm I guess you'll have to hack the table plugin or clone the table plugin and customize it and disable the original table plugin.